# Помогите пожалуйста перевести код с С++ на pascal

Tags: c++, pascal

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int A [6][6];
int B[6];

//Massivty toltyru
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
    A[i][j]= rand()%6;

for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
        cout<<A[i][j]<<"\t";
    cout<<endl;}
 cout<<endl;
 for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
B[i]=0;

for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
            switch(j-i)
            {
                case 0:if(A[i][j]==0) B[j-i]+=1;break;
                case 1:if(A[i][j]==0) B[j-i]+=1;break;
                case 2:if(A[i][j]==0) B[j-i]+=1;break;
                case 3:if(A[i][j]==0) B[j-i]+=1;break;
                case 4:if(A[i][j]==0) B[j-i]+=1;break;
                case 5:if(A[i][j]==0) B[j-i]+=1;break;
            }
        }

}
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
cout<<B[i]<<"\t";
}
```

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

смотри, там ничего сложно нет, если ты знаешь паскаль, то труда перевести не составит. `cout<<` - меняешь на вывод как в паскале (вроде там writeline,точно не помню ) `for(int i:=0;i<6;i++)` - это равносильно `for i=0 to 6 do begin` (вроде бы так, давно не писал ) `switch` - это как бы некая проверка, в зависимости от того, что получил (от 0 до 5) выполняется определенное действие (в данном случае одно и то же, и смысла в switch не вижу) - можно заменить обычным if'ом. Остальное , по сути, тоже самое, A,B - это массивы, двумерный и одинарный

```
= это :=

B[j-i]+=1 - это B[j-i]:=B[j-i]+1;

break; - это выход 


type 
A = array [1..6, 1..6] of integer;
B = array [1..6] of integer;

integer i,j;
...
for i:=0 to 6 do  

for j:=0 to 6 do 
A[i][j]:=random() mod 6; // vot tut ne uveren

for i:=0 to 6 do  
for j:=0 to 6 do 
writeline(A[i][j]);

for i:=0 to 6 do 
B[i]:=0;

for i:=0 to 6 do  
for j:=0 to 6 do 
if ( (j-i)>0 and (j-i)<6) then
 if A[i][j] =0 then begin B[j-i]=B[j-i]+1;
break; // tut ne uveren, poishite v gugle vixod 
end;

for i:=0 to 6 do 
writeline(B[i]);
```

писал сразу сюда, незначительные шибки сами исправите